# communication between DefaultComboBoxModel and JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am using DefaultComboBoxModel to manage the data for various JComboBoxes in my app.

I would like to disable these comboboxes while the data is loading or reloading (or display a "loading..." text and set the pointer to a hourglass).

Is there a way for the JComboBox to be informed that the model is reloading the data ?

The reloading is occuring in a separate thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `AbstractListModel` is a function called `addListDataListener(ListDataListener l)`. Now you are able to implement your own Listener that will be informed when the method `fireContentsChanged(Object source, int index0, int index1)` is called (This will be done in background, you don't need to do this).

[AbstractListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html)

Answer (score 3):

- remove all [Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html) from [JComboBox(es)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) untill refresh ended (one void)
- show [GlassPane, put there description to the JLabel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) (notice to consume only mouse event, have to override events from keyboard) or [(better could be to use) JLayer for Java7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html), based on `JXLayer (Java6)`
- if ended all data loading then to add all [Listeners](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/eventsandcomponents.html) back to [JComboBox(es)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) (one void)

Comment: The problem I have is that my model doesn't have any references the the JComboboxes

Comment: then have to accepting that all Listeners added to the JComboBox could be fired events, I'm talking about clean and confortable way

Answer (score 3):

I would use a SwingWorker for the background task, I would call `setEnabled(false)` on the JComboBoxes while the SwingWorker's background thread is running, and then would re-enable the JComboBoxes when the thread is done. This can be determined by adding a PropertyChangeListener to the SwingWorker listening to its state property and being notified when it is StateValue.DONE. Note that the models themselves should be updated on the Swing event thread only. So for instance if the data is coming in from a database, get the information from the database in the background thread, but pass it to the combo box's model on the event thread. A SwingWorker's process/publish method pair would be a good way to do this.